# Spring Data REST, cannot save, can select

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm puzzled as to why my Spring Data REST code was working, but not anymore. Probably a configuration issue, but I can't point my finger to what. When I use AJAX to post to a endpoint, I get a 500 error - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`. When I try `repository.save()` from independent java, I get no response. On the other hand, when I perform a get to my API or call `repository.find()`, I can see Hibernate showing selects happening. So I know that my database is connected. Additionally, I'm using Flyway and those scripts are able to insert without issue.

I'm using Spring-Boot-Starter for Data-REST, Data-JPA, and thymeleaf, all Version 1.2.1.RELEASE. I recognize that this could be a version issue, but I'm keeping it here to eventually integrate with Spring-Security-Kerberos, which I know works with that version of Spring-Boot. At least, I haven't gotten it to work with a later version of Spring-Boot.

Some things I have noticed that may or may not be related:

- `@Transactional` on top my `@RestRepositoryResource` makes no difference
- When calling `repository.save()`, the returned entity's ID stays at 0 (I'm Auto generation on my entities)
- The problem exists on all my entities, including ones without any relations
- It didn't matter that I removed unique=true from one of my entities

#### One of my Repository Interfaces

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "shifts", path = "shifts")
public interface ShiftRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Shift, Long> {
    List<Shift> findBySiteId(@Param("siteId") String siteId);
    Shift findByShiftCode(@Param("shiftCode") String shiftCode);
}
```

#### My Repository Config Component

```
@Component
public class RepositoryConfigDev {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    EventHandler eventHandler() {
        return new EventHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        return adapter;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        emfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emfb.setPackagesToScan("package.model");
        emfb.afterPropertiesSet();
        return emfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        txManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after rebuilding from scratch, I figured out what I did wrong. The problem was in the `@RepositoryEventHandler`. In that I had originally declared the class as

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(value={Class1.class, Class2.class})
public class RepoEvents {
    ....
}
```

When it should have been

```
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class RepoEvents {
    @HandleBeforeCreate(Class1.class)
    public void beforeCreate1(Class1 c) { ... }

    @HandleBeforeCreate(Class2.class)
    public void beforeCreate2(Class2 c) { ... }
}
```